# Spread items in multiple .NET collections

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I am using VS 2015 to write a windows form application in C sharp.
In this application, I have a string collection (List) that contain the names of multiple sport teams. I want to divide these sport teams into several groups. The number of groups that will be created are based on the number of sport teams in my string collection. For example, if I have less than 8 teams, I will spread the teams over two groups. My problem is that I cannot find a way to divide my items in my string collection over two new string collections.
Underlying code shows that I can create on group and adding the string items but making two groups and spreading the items over these two new string collections is a problem for me. Feel free to give me some tips or help :

```
   if (i < 6)
   {
   /// Make one group and add the teams in this group
   List<string> groepa = new List<string>();
   foreach (var item in lstTeams)
   {
   groepa.Add(item);

   }

   }
   else if (i < 8)
   {
   /// Make two groups
   List<string> groepa = new List<string>();
   List<string> groepb = new List<string>();
```

Comment: Maybe Take (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) and Skip (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can divide the number of elements in the main list by two. Then take the first half and put them in a first list, the second half goes to the second list

```
int numElements = lstTeams / 2;
List<string> groepa = lstTeams.Take(numElements).ToList();
List<string> groepb = lstTeams.Skip(numElements).ToList();
```

This uses the IEnumerable extensions Take and Skip

Comment: You can omit the call to `Take(...)` in constructing `groepB`. Skipping 1 element and calling `ToList` will enumerate the remaining elements.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and also a very good answer. I was just wondering if I divide an uneven number of elements by 2 ? Will it round up/down ? For example 7 / 2 is 3.5, will it take 3 elements for the first half and four for the second?

Comment: please ignore the question in my last comment. Thank you for your help. I will mark this topic as answered.

Comment: @Steve, of course, `Skip(#).Take(#)` would be applicable in extending this to a case with three or more groups, where you need to limit the greediness of the middle groups.